# Cannot check the radio button in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can anybody help me with this radio buttons, don't have any minds about this. I need to check an element with `value="inside"`

My code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[string(@value)='inside']")).Click();
```

Fails with error "The xpath expression cannot be evaluated or does not result in a WebElement"
Working with C# and IEdriver.

Below is the DOM:

```
<td colspan="3">
                    Fieldnames

    <label>
        <input name="labelPosition-step-1" type="radio" value="above" checked="checked">
        Above
    </label>
            Or

    <label>
        <input name="labelPosition-step-1" type="radio" value="inside">
        Inside
    </label>
            Or

    <label>
        <input name="labelPosition-step-1" type="radio" value="left">
        Left
    </label>


</td>
```

Comment: You should create generic xpaths that grabs the element properly and you get the value of such element dynamically. If you be specific with value in xpath then number of lines of similar code will increase. Make sure your xpaths are optimized and as answered by Jens Erat, that would be proper xpath but additionally you can also specify type and value both attributes as `//input[@type='radio' and @value='inside']` or just `//input[@type=radio]` that retrieves all radio input elements and you can get the value of those by iterating over the list of `WebElements` achieved by `driver.findElements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression lacks the element you're looking for, and thus is invalid.

I'm guessing you're only searching `<input>` elements. I also removed the unnecessary `string(...)` function call.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='inside']")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Helped me a lot, but i tried "//input[@value=inside]" and its not found. Is '' symbols is increasing efficiency of element search?

Comment: That query is looking for input elements, whose `@value` attribute value equals the text contents of an `<inside/>` element's child (something like `<input value="foo"><inside>bar</inside></input>`). Without quotes, you compare with a node, with quotes, you compare with a string.

Answer (score 1):

I had to get all the options and loop through them

```
IWebElement option = driver.FindElement(By.Id("labelPosittion-step-1"));
//List<IWebElement> Links = new List<IWebElement>(option.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tbody/tr/td")));
List<IWebElement> Links = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.ID("labelPosittion-step-1")));    

for (int k = 0; k < Links.Count; k++)
{
    if (Links[k].Text == "inside")
    {
    option = Links[k];
    }
}
option.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[value='inside']")).Click();
```

Xpath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value,'inside']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with combination of two attributes,

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='radio'][value='inside']")).Click();
```

Comment: ah, ty, that will help me in future!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper library for creating xpath expressions using c# linq-esq syntax. Posting in case you find it helpful.

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-create-xpath-using-linq

Example

```
var xpath = CreateXpath.Where(e => e.TargetElementName == "input" 
                  && e.Attribute("value").Text == "inside");
```

Generated xpath:

```
"//input[@value='inside']"
```